# AngularJS - How do I know immediately when an input has been changed if it is debounced?

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-change

Having a text input I want to know immediately when the user is changing the text, but also I want to use the debounce feature. This way I can, for example, disable a submit button while the user is changing the text and enable the submit button after checking the text in the debounced function.

Is there a way to do this with pure AngularJS? Or should I use javascript/jquery?

With this code I am only able to know when the user has changed the text after the debounce 500ms delay:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <script src="http://localhost/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app= angular.module('app',[]);

            app.controller('ExampleController',['$scope',function($scope){
                $scope.changed= '';
                $scope.change= function(){
                    $scope.changed= 'Changed!';
                };
            }]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <div>Message: <input type="text" ng-model="model.message"
            ng-model-options="{debounce:500}" ng-change="change()" />

        <div>{{model.message}}</div>
        <div>{{changed}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean debounce ?

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi this option creates a delay between the user interaction and the update of the model.

Comment: debouncing for 500ms is quite extreme I think, usually I would expect about 250ms, 500 seems like nothing is work - maybe causing a jarring user experience?

Comment: @callum-linington this is just an example.

Comment: For what I see there is no way to do what I asked, so I will do the opposite; don't debounce and call my own debounce function on each change. I will try with underscore library's debounce.

Answer (score 0):

Your main option is to write your own debouncing code using `ng-keyup`. Every time a key is pressed, you will be notified of the change (and the change will be present in the `ng-model` value) and you can use your own `setTimeout` there, with the desired debounce function as the callback. If the timeout is already set, simply cancel it and restart it on each key press.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope.$watch('model-name', function(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('customControl').
directive('contenteditable', [function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
    require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model        
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
            // do what you want to happen before "debounce"
            // debounce here by waiting 500ms
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

source: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to do this in a simple way I've finished doing it outside of angular with underscore library. That is the best option that I have found.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <script src="http://localhost/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/js/underscore.js"></script>
        <script>
            var underscore= angular.module('underscore',[]);

            underscore.factory('_',function(){
                return window._; // assumes underscore has already been loaded on the page
            });

            var app= angular.module('app',['underscore']);

            app.controller('ExampleController',['$scope','_',function($scope,_){
                $scope.changed= '';

                $scope.change= function(){
                    $scope.debounceMessage($scope);
                };

                $scope.debounceMessage= _.debounce(function($scope){
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                        $scope.changed= 'Delayed: '+$scope.model.message;
                    });
                }, 500);

            }]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <div>Message: <input type="text" ng-model="model.message"
            ng-change="change()" />

        <div>{{model.message}}</div>
        <div>{{changed}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0gnwg9